# Maven + AssertJ + IntelliJ = confusion with scope?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, assertj

I want to add a test framework to my current maven project in IntelliJ.

I choose AsserJ, because the style looked best to me. I tried their tutorial, but it fails to provide enough help. (http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-quick-start.html)

My issues is that the scope "test" is not explained well enough. With that scope I cant even import the necessary AsserJ files.
When I try "import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;", the import is not recognized and it says that Assertions cant be resolved.

Any suggestions that might help?

Comment: what is the structure of your code?

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html might help. As "test" scope will only work for classes that are under the src/test/java file directory

Comment: Thank you. I had found that page before, but it didnt solve my confusion. Your post did help me though, even if it contained the same info that is on that page!  
Should I delete this question now, since it was maybe somewhat stupid? Or post your comment as the answer that helped?

Comment: Ill post as an answer, to try and claim all of that glorious reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the structure of your code?

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html might help.

"Test" scope imports libraries that are only available to classes that are under src/test/java

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39833131/642706) is correct, but lacks details.

## Maven

Add your `dependency` element for AssertJ in the `dependencies` element of your POM.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

## Delete `<scope>test</scope>`

If you are trying to use the AssertJ assertions outside of test classes, in your regular app classes, then pay attention to the `scope` element. This topic was addressed in a [closed ticket # 520](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39833131/642706) on the AssertJ issue tracker.

When a Maven dependency carries a `scope` element with a value of `test`, that means you cannot use that library outside of your test-specific source package/folder.

If you are trying to call AssertJ from code in your example project’s `src/main/java/…` folder hierarchy, you will see that error. If you call AssertJ from `src/test/java…`, you will see success.

To enable AssertJ in the `src/main/java/…` folder hierarchy, delete the `scope` element in your POM dependency. So this:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

…becomes this:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

## Java 8 required

AssertJ 3 requires Java 8 or later.

Verify the version of Java used by your compiler. In Maven verify this pair of elements:

```xml
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

Comment: I believe the comment about "closed ticket #520" is meant to hyperlink to https://github.com/assertj/assertj/issues/520#issuecomment-156573016